# Create a checklist with subitems in Django

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a model with questions called questions and then a model called Answers (related to Questions through a ForeignKey) with different answers for every question.How can I create a form that creates a checklist with the questions, and has every answer pertaining to that question bellow them like a subitem? like this:

[]What is 1+1?

A)1
   B)2
   C)3
   D)4

Currently what I have is this:

```
class ChecklistForm(forms.Form):
       question= Question.objects.all()

 Checklist=forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,queryset=question,)
```

But I have no clue how I could add the answers as subitems.

If checked I would also like to retrieve the question and all the answers bellow it. Is that possible?

UPDATE:
This is what I'm trying to do, but using forms  salty-lowlands-6607.herokuapp.com

Answer (score 0):

If you have fixed count of questions you can do

```
class ChecklistForm(forms.Form):
    answer1 = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
                           queryset=Answer.objects.filter(question=question1))
    ...
    answer5 = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
                           queryset=Answer.objects.filter(question=question5))
```

If you would like to create form for all questions that exists in database, you can create such form class on the fly

```
fields = {}

for question in Questions.objects.all():
    fields['answer{}'.format(question.pk)] =
        forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
                           queryset=Answer.objects.filter(question=question)) 

ChecklistForm = type('CheckListForm', (forms.Form,), fields)
```

Beware, don't do this in module top level, b/c it will create form class ones, on project start, no new question will be added if it appears in database later. Put this forms class creation code inside your view.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, but your solution creates a checkbox for each answer. What I would like is to create only one checkbox per question with all the answers bellow them, so if that question is chosen I can retrieve the question itself and all the answers. I was able to create it using the template language and you can see it here https://salty-lowlands-6607.herokuapp.com/ but it is too messy and I would rather make that using the forms.

Comment: heroku link is dead. can you post a screenshot & an answer if you got it working?